# how can i detect running specific applications

Tags: java, android, background

i want to detect gallery applications running using service

so i found ActivityManager 
but it returned only running service own application

here is my java code

```
            ActivityManager actMng = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            String strPackage = "";
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> list = actMng.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                Log.d("test",list.get(i).processName);
            }
```

how can i detect gallery application run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Code:

```
ActivityManager activity_manager = (ActivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Using Activity Manager to list all running apps:

```
final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final List<RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) 
{
    Log.d("Running apps", "Application executed : " +recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString()+ "\t\t ID: "+recentTasks.get(i).id+"");         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++)
        {
            if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("yourProgram")) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "yourProgram is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```